# Bootstrap Nav Breaks Out of Navbar container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange problem with the responsive bootstrap website I am trying to create. I have the website looking fine but when I resize to a 996 breakpoint, the nav suddenly looks like this:
[image: nav problem]

BUT it looks like it works fine on codepen? https://codepen.io/Sovember/full/GrgrxQ/

Why is it working on codepen and not on my local? Is google chrome maybe adding styles or something? 
HTML

```
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
  <img src="img/brand.jpg" class="navbar-brand" alt="" id="navbar-brand" >
      </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" >
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav  pull-right" id="myNavbar2"  >
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#How">How It Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Get">Get Started</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar .in .nav li {
   display: inline;
   float: none;
   width:100%;

}


.navbar {


    height: 12%;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color:white;
}



#navbar-brand{

    height: 2%;
    width: 39%;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.nav li a {

    padding-top: 24px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;

     color:#113672;
  /* First we need to help some browsers along for this to work.
     Just because a vendor prefix is there, doesn't mean it will
     work in a browser made by that vendor either, it's just for
     future-proofing purposes I guess. */
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.5s;

}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #729adb;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #729adb;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle  URL to give you the correct answer to you

Comment: Please share the working example link where we can see the issue.

Comment: you must have some other differences because the codepen is working. double check for spelling errors on class names and make sure that you are targeting ids or classes appropriately

Comment: You can past full html code and also more picture related. So that can help us

Comment: thank you i will do this in a minute

Comment: just checked. the html and css is exactly the same in my broswer version, it's just doing different things when i run it locally, i am at a loss